# HTML5 - header tag

Tags: html, validation

I just was wondering about the following code ...

```
<table><tr><th>
<header><h1>...</h1></header>
</th></tr></table>
```

gives me two errors when I validate it with W3C validator.

1. The element header must not appear as a descendant of the th element.
2. The element h1 must not appear as a descendant of the th element.

But ...

```
<table><tr><td>
<header><h1>...</h1></header>
</td></tr></table>
```

seems to be OK. I don't get any error messages.
Is this an oversight of the validator or are actually both codes wrong?

Thanks ...

B

Comment: A `th` is already a header.  I see no reason to wrap it in a further `header` container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an oversight.  It is as described in the spec:

`<th>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element

> Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or heading content descendants

[`<td>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element) is just flow content with no other restrictions.